# Animate.css Not working

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am using [animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/) but it don't seem to work in firefox. The code I am using is:

```
       <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="rotateIn"> content</div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I want this div to show rotate in effect when we load the page but it don't seem to work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you have to use `animated` class if you want to show animations try this

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="animated rotateIn"> content</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 12):

Long story short: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZLLm/

[image]

You **MUST** use the `animated` class provided.

So, to add further, it should be:

```
<div class="animated rotateIn"> content</div>
```