# Animate.css not animating in my Vue 3 project

Tags: html, css, vue.js, animation, animate.css

I'm simply trying to do some basic html animations in my Vue 3 app but the Animate.css examples aren't working.

Specifically, after installing the animate css dependency using `npm install animate.css --save` the sample animation code `<h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce">An animated element</h1>` doesn't animate when my page loads. The header renders but just sits there, motionless.

I've tried other solutions like [changing windows performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022493/animate-css-is-not-working-in-chrome-latest-version-version-above-73), [adding `animated` to the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920288/animate-css-not-working), etc, but it hasn't worked.

I see some solutions use CDN to link the library, but I don't think I should have to do that since I used npm to install it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="app">
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce" style="color:white">An animated element</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: After doing npm install, what steps did you take to make sure it is included in your sites css files?

Comment: @JoshuaAngnoe None, I didn't realize that was a requirement; simply following the docs as written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

import animate.css into your main.js file

```
import 'animate.css';
```